# Using a database with a tablsorter

Tags: jquery, database, tablesorter

I'm confused on:
How to create a database
and
How to fetch data from a database into a jquery tablesorter

I wondered if anyone could point me in the direction of any documents, forum posts or anything that can help me. Thanks.

Comment: you should be more specific, give some ideas of what you've tried and some example of what isn't working

Comment: At the moment I have created a jquery tablesorter. However I have too much data to manually add in the HTML. So I've looked at creating a database were all the information would go. However I don't know whats the best software or way to create a databse and how you would then go about linking it to your tablesorter, thats why I'm asking if there is anything out there to help.

Comment: then questions not really a good fit here, it will be closed as 'too broad' - it would be better to do some investigation and get yourself to a state where you can ask a more specific question about an individual problem

Comment: plus also, asking for links doesn't fit too well with the idea that Stack Exchange should be a single point of call to solve a problem - if links are put in without explanation and those links disappear the answer becomes useless - it's considered a bad answer to just link to other places without summarising and leaving the OP with a solution to their problem, but with links that allow them to do extra reading but that aren't essential to the solution

Comment: Some topics to look into; MySQL, PHP, Apache.

Answer (score 0):

As a step towards understanding databases you could use Excel or a similar spreadsheet that you can save as HTML to handle larger tables. The structure is like a database table with rows and columns. It will not be as dynamic as a database.